# Unexpected result from TSQL "between" statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've just been experimenting with the "between" statement in TSQL the following code returns "true":

```
declare @Value as decimal
declare @Upper as decimal
declare @Lower as decimal

set @Value = 20.1
set @Lower = 10.0
set @Upper = 20.0

select 
    case
    when @Value between @Lower and @Upper then 'true'
        else 'false'
    end as Result
```

If I change @Value to be 20.5, the result is "false", but 20.4 returns "true". It would appear that TSQL is using "banker's rounding" for decimal values.

If I change the variables to "money", I get the expected result, that is, @Value = 20.1 returns "false".

Comment: Using just `decimal` is equivalen to `decimal(18,0)` - with **0** digits after the decimal point. So therefore, you're digits after the comma are *shaved off** and your values `20.0` and `20.1` become identical - `20` ....

Answer (score 5):

Just to clarify a bit more what happened, had you simply printed your variables and you would have found out that their values were 20, 10 and 20 respectively.

`decimal`'s default precision and scale are 18 and 0, so `decimal` = `decimal(18,0)`. That's why you lost your decimals there.
You didn't have this issue with `money` as it has a precision of 4 decimals.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

SQL is not using banker's rounding. .5 is always rounded up: `20.5 -> 21`, `21.5 -> 22`. With banker's rounding, 20.5 would be rounded to 20.

Comment: You're quite right, I should have output the variables, which would have made the problem obvious. I didn't know that about banker's rounding - helpful to know!

Answer (score 4):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I forgot to specify the number of decimal points in the decimal variables. For example, the following code returns "false" as it should:

```
declare @Value as decimal(18,2)
declare @Upper as decimal(18,2)
declare @Lower as decimal(18,2)

set @Value = 20.1
set @Lower = 10
set @Upper = 20

select 
    case
        when @Value between @Lower and @Upper then 'true'
        else 'false'
    end as Result
```

Essentially, my original query was using whole numbers instead of floating-point values.